# Move one DIV's content into another DIV in certain width @media (max-width: 767px){}

Tags: jquery, css

I have a three column layout with banners on left and right. It's created with Bootstrap. My Structure is like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 left">Left banner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">Page Contents</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 right">Right banner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 left mobile-view">Left banner copy here when screen is 767px</div>
</div>
```

Now, I have made this with @media query by `display: none;` and `display: block;` on separate view-port. Can this be done with jQuery like I need to only use left banner and contents will be copied to second left panel in smaller screen?

Comment: If you sum up the total size of columns you get to 14, bootstrap scaffolding max size is 12, you need to resize them.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is reorder the colums for the mobie view..so that your content is at the top and banners below. In that case, look at `column ordering` in `Bootstrap`

Comment: It worked with `column ordering` Thanks Sandeep Nayak